# How to add a source to a stripe customer?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to create a subscription with stripe, and in their docs they add a hard coded source, but i assume this should be generated for each user...
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart

how do i create this source?

when a user makes a payment, the action on the form takes them to a controller that does this:

```
exports.goProPay = async (req, res) => {

  const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
    email: req.body.email,
  });

  const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
    customer: customer.id,
    items: [{plan: 'plan_ElVkJ345s0xwbw'}],
  });

  res.render('homepage', { title: 'Homepage' });
};
```

i am supposed to add a source on the subscription function, but how?
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart

Comment: `You can securely collect a customer’s payment information via Checkout, Elements, or Stripe’s iOS and Android SDKs.` — you would collect payment information from the customer, using those. You end up with a `tok_xxx` or `src_xxx` ID which is a payment token you can save to a customer by setting it as the `source` parameter on `stripe.customers.create`

Comment: I already have added a form which is the button, as they do in the quickstart: https://stripe.com/docs/quickstart isnt that the same?